# idpiframe_initialization_failed with Angular project

Tags: angular, google-signin

I have added `http://localhost:4200` in Authorized JavaScript origins in Google Credentials.

But I'm still getting the same error when I try to click on Login with Google.

Here is my code:

I added below js import in my `index.html` file

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```

Component file code:

```
declare const gapi: any;

clientId:string = '248871214048- 
rkg3p17piu27bl2o58fftdoq43cepb37.apps.googleusercontent.com';
 private scope = [
'profile',
'email',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly'
 ].join(' ');

public auth2: any;

  public googleInit() {
gapi.load('auth2', () => {
   this.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
     client_id: this.clientId,
     cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
     scope: this.scope
   });
   this.attachSignin(this.element.nativeElement.firstChild);
 });
   }

   public attachSignin(element) {
this.auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
  (googleUser) => {
    let profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    console.log('Token || ' + googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token);
    console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId());
    // ...
  }, function (error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
  });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
this.googleInit();
  }
```